# E: Unable to locate package bfgminer

Tags: apt, linaro

I recently set up cubieboard with Linaro Ubuntu 12.04 installed.

Everything seems to be okay when i try to run these commands:

```
linaro@cubieboard:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unit3/bfgminer
sudo: unable to resolve host cubieboard
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 A CPU+GPU+FPGA miner for bitcoins (and other compatible coins), by Luke Dashjr and others:
https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer

 More info: https://launchpad.net/~unit3/+archive/bfgminer
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpko9l37/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpko9l37/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 0AE7FCDA from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpko9l37/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 0AE7FCDA: public key "Launchpad PPA for Graeme" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
```

Then:

```
linaro@cubieboard:~$ sudo apt-get update
sudo: unable to resolve host cubieboard
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease 
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal Release    
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [316 B]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release    
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release   
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources                  
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release [11.9 kB]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe armhf Packages              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main armhf Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main armhf Packages
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources [653 B]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main armhf Packages [14 B]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
Fetched 12.8 kB in 3s (4033 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

And:

```
linaro@cubieboard:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo: unable to resolve host cubieboard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After that I get error when trying to install bfgminer:

```
linaro@cubieboard:~$ sudo apt-get install bfgminer
sudo: unable to resolve host cubieboard
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bfgminer
```

I have added bfgminer repositories before to /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ quantal main universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ quantal main universe
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/unit3/bfgminer/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/unit3/bfgminer/ubuntu quantal main
```

Don't know why this happens! Waiting for your help.

Comment: You shouldn't mix quantal and precise repositories. Just don't.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some dependency issues with bfgminer. To force install, try the following:

- Download bfgminer from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~unit3/+archive/bfgminer/+files/bfgminer_3.2.1-0precise1_i386.deb)
- Open a terminal and type `sudo dpkg --force-all -i bfgminer_3.2.1-0precise1_i386.deb`
- And `sudo apt-get install libjansson4`

**Source:** [github bug on bfgminer](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/issues/94). Updated the package for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: But this is i386 version, while cubie needs armhf, because it has Allwiner processor. Will it work?

Comment: Do you mean you need the package for AMD 64-bit processor? Sorry, I have never heard of a package for Allwinner processor(or the processor itself).

Comment: No, Allwiner processor is from ARM family, so I need armhf package. Here is a link to various architecture packages: http://ppa.launchpad.net/unit3/bfgminer/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/

Comment: But I don't know how to build .deb file from them..

Comment: Can I somehow use i386 package on armhf system?

Comment: I am not sure, may be you should post a question regarding this(?)

Comment: even if you could use an i386 package on armhf via emulation, it seems hardly to make sense for a workload like a bitcoin miner...